# How to get selected value from dropdown, so it can be used in a mysql statement

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Is it possible to create a function that allows you to get the selected value from a dropdown, so it can be used in a mysql statement that can print_r out some informations?

I have everything in one page. This is my page after i stripped out some non relevant informations.

Php

```
"SELECT emd.m_field_id_8 as refer
FROM transactions as t
left join exp_members as em on (t.cardid-10000000 = em.member_id) 
left JOIN exp_member_data emd on em.member_id = emd.member_id
Group BY emd.m_field_id_8 limit 20");


foreach ($resultsdropdown->result_array() as $key)
{
$array1[] = array("Refer" => $key['refer']);
}
```

Html head.

```
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#button1').click(function(){ 
            alert($('#combo').val());
    });
});
</script>
```

Html body.

```
<select id="combo">
<?
foreach($array1 as $key => $value)
{
echo'<option value="'.$value['Refer'].'">'.$value['Refer'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Click!" />
```

This is the place where i get stuck.

The idea was to get the variable from my javascript, so it can be used in a mysql statement that can print_r out some informations?

This is mysql statement where i want to put my selected variables from my dropdown.

```
"SELECT t.*, em.*, emd.*
FROM transactions as t
left join exp_members as em on (t.cardid-10000000 = em.member_id) 
left JOIN exp_member_data emd on em.member_id = emd.member_id
ORDER BY t.created where emd.m_field_id_8 = 'VARIABLE?'");
```

But i dont know where to put my sql? I cant put in the php area, as javascript cant send variables to php. And the other problem is how get the selected variables from my dropdown in to mysql..

Do you got any ideas? I hope you can help. Just ask me if you got any questions.

Comment: I think you want to do this without a page reload? Use AJAX, otherwise, simply submit the form, and give your selectfield a name attribut and access the value by it (for example $_POST['nameOfField'])

Answer (score 0):

put the HTML part on one page and write the query on the other page like below:

```
$query = "SELECT t.*, em.*, emd.*
FROM transactions as t
left join exp_members as em on (t.cardid-10000000 = em.member_id) 
left JOIN exp_member_data emd on em.member_id = emd.member_id
ORDER BY t.created where emd.m_field_id_8 = 'VARIABLE?')";

mysql_query($query);
```

now try using Ajax from the HTML page to get the data from the query from the php page created by you.

Refer to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ to see how ajax can be implemented.

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#button1').click(function(){ 
            var comboValue = $('#combo').val();
    });
});
</script>
```

Try send javascript variable comboValue through ajax to the php file and there you will be able to utilize it as per your need and you can get the response on the same HTML page

Answer (score 0):

(EDIT)
NOTE: I am considering that you know how to get the values of form elements on the server side.

If you need to update your page as soon as you select a value from the dropdown .. consider using ajax.. either the pure javascript way or you can use the jquery's ajax(which in my opinion is much simpler to learn and use).

The second way is that you can post your page on the selection of a new value in your dropdown(using javascript). The page refreshes with the new content according to your selection.

I hope it helps.
here you can find about jquery's ajax.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
You can search for more resources in a search engine.